# How delete the particler column through the jquery

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

Hi here i am using jquery to delete the records in the table but once I delete the record that record is coming back while updating. But if I do cancel with out doing updating that record is not coming.But the record is delete fine in the database.Can anyone plz solve my problem by seeing my code where I went wrong plz assist me.

**Jquery code**

```
 $('button[id*="delid"]').click(function() {
                    var cnfrm = confirm("Do you really want to delete this");
                    if (cnfrm == true) {
                        var a = "trid" + $(this).val();
                        var tcopies = $("#abc").val();
    //                    alert(a);
    //                    var slno = $('#' + a).find('td:first').text();
    //                alert("alert" + $(this).val());
                        $.ajax({type: 'POST', url: 'deletebar.do?id=' + $(this).val(), success: function(result) {
                                if (result == 'success') {
                                    $('#' + a).remove();
                                    $("#abc").val(--tcopies);
                                    $("#jkl").val(tcopies);
    //                                $('#cancel').attr('disabled', true);
    // $('#vehicletab tr').each(function() {
    //                                    var i = $(this).find('td:first').text();
    //                                    if (i > slno) {
    //                                        --i;
    //                                    }
    //                                    $(this).find('td:first').html(i);
    //                                })
                                    alert("Deleted Successfully", "Success");
                                } else {
                                    alert("This vehicle is assigned to Route, You can't Delete it", "Error");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

**Jsp Code**

```
  <c:forEach var="lib" items="${list}">
                                                <table>
                                                    <tr id="trid${lib.slno}">
                                                        <td>
                                                            <label class="control-label" for="typeahead">Bar Code No&nbsp:&nbsp&nbsp</label>
                                                            <input type="text" name="barcode" value="${lib.getbarcode}" readonly="true"/>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <label class="control-label" for="typeahead">Accession No&nbsp:&nbsp&nbsp</label>
                                                            <input type="text" name="accessno" value="${lib.acession}"/>
                                                        </td> 
                                                        <td>
                                                            <button type="button" id="delid${lib.slno}" value="${lib.slno}">Delete</button>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>                                              
                                            </c:forEach>                                                     
                                        </c:forEach>
```

Comment: are you deleting it from database or just marking as deleted?

Comment: deleting from database.

Comment: The value displaying may be due to browser caching..add some random values along with url as querystring and please check. example http://www.myurl.com?randomVal=somerandomValue.